# Unable to connect to sql server 2008 with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SQL Server on one PC and I have created a c# program on another computer to connect to the server. However, when I run my program, I get an exception saying that login failed for user 'testing'.

This is the code used to connect:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IP,PORT;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Stockinfo;uid=testing;pwd=testing");
```

I have created a login in the server with userid and password as testing. As for the server authentication, it has been set to SQL Server and Windows authentication. I have also created an exception for firewall. What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT 1: I am able to access the server with SQL Server authentication using the same userid and password on the computer running the server.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Login failed for user 'testing'.

Comment: You say you've created a **login** on that server - that's just the first step. Have you also created a **user** (for that login) in that particular database (`Stockinfo`) ??

Comment: Yes i have created a user for that particular database

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Sql Server Management Studio. If yes, then you can open it and right click the instance in question, go to Properties -> Connections -> Check "Allow remote connections to this server".

You might also have to enable TCP/IP Protocol to be enabled thru Configuration Manager.

Does it return this error?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**[You can check this link: enable remote connections in SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)**

Another reason is to check another computer's firewall if port `sqlbrowser` (*or port 1433 is open*) was added on its firewall.

**UPDATE 1**

user `testing` simply doesn't exist or you have supplied `incorrect password`

Comment: TCP/IP protocol is enabled remote connection is allowed as well. It only returns that error message if i typed in the ip and port wrongly and as for the port i have opened port 1433

Comment: can you connect if this connectionstring format is used? `Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Comment: @chuawoohian where is your remote pc located? inside lan or outside wan?

Comment: both laptops are connected wirelessly to a network. I dont think theres lan connection. Will a lan connection help in my case?

Comment: try to ping each laptop from one another. does it return ping time?

Comment: By that do you mean that i use the cmd.exe to ping the IP address? If so then yes i am able to ping them. However, i think i am doing something wrongly, even after i stopped sql server, i am still able to ping to that ip address

Comment: we cannot go to chat since you don't have enough reputation. is [**SQLBrowser**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724(v=sql.90).aspx) running on your server's machine?

Comment: Yes SQL server browser is running

Answer (score 0):

> Login failed for user 'testing'.

That usually means that the user doesn't have access to that database.

Comment: How do i check if the login have access to that database? Also, i am able to connect to the server using microsoft sql server management studios with sql authentication using the user id and password(On the server side PC)